# How to get all Facebook posts for a particular user using Graph API

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

like the subject states I would like to get a list of (public) posts for some user.
I was expecting that "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=from%3Dsome_user&type=post" might work but I'm getting nothing.

Assume that xxx is either a valid user name or id where person don't necessary need to be in any relation with the person whose access token is used (in case the AT is needed).

Is this even possible? Any ideas?

EDIT: If nothing, I will go with "https://graph.facebook.com/user-id/posts" but I would really like  to get access to public posts via "search".

Thanks in advance.

p.s. I'm working on Android but not using the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like searching for posts that way would be efficient on either end.

If you have the user's id then use the posts, feed, or home.

Facebook says:

> You can also search an individual user's News Feed, restricted to that
>   user's friends, by adding a q argument to the home connection URL:
>
> News Feed: https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?q=facebook

From there you could add the from.id with correct privacy responses to a separate object.